# Is there any way to loop through an array without using pairs()?

Tags: arrays, loops, lua

I can iterate through an array/table (for example `{'a', 'b', 'c'}`) using a regular `for` loop. And then there is iteration using `pairs`

```
for _, v in pairs({'a', 'b', 'c'}) do
  io.write(v..'\n')
end
```

but when I have a plain old array, I really don't find myself caring about the keys.

Is there a way of iterating like

```
for value in array do end
```

I do see instances of this. For example I'm using a library to create a map in my game and I see you can access objects in a map layer like this

```
for object in map.layer["platform"].nameIs("platform") do
```

Any way to iterate like this?

Comment: I find myself needing the key a lot. When you only want to iterate over the array part, ipairs is the way to go.

Comment: And your IDE will FOREVER pester you about every last one of the gazilliard unused index variables in your code. This SUCKS ROYALLY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and i see you can access objects in a map layer like this 
>   **for object in map.layer["platform"].nameIs("platform") do**

What you see here is nothing else than generic for used with custom iterator.
`.nameIs("platform")` returns functions that essentially behaves like ipairs.

For example, that syntax might be implemented like this (though it's not what your library might do actually):

```
local object = {
    platform = {1,2,3,4},
    mob = {4,3,2,1}
}

function object.nameIs(idx)
    local array = object[idx]
    local i = 0
    return function ()
        i = i+1
        return array[i]
    end
end

print "-- Platforms --"
for value in object.nameIs("platform") do
    print(value)
end

print "-- Mobs --"
for value in object.nameIs("mob") do
    print(value)
end
```

For more detailed explanation see "Programming in Lua" online book, you want to see section [7 - Iterators and the Generic For](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html)

Answer (score 7):

For arrays, the natural way is to use `ipairs`, not `pairs`. However, it still needs a key:

```
for _, v in arr do
```

If you really want to avoid the key item, make your own iterator. *Programming in Lua* provides one as an example:

```
function values(t)
    local i = 0
    return function() i = i + 1; return t[i] end
end
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
local arr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
for e in values(arr) do
    print(e)
end
```

Comment: Are you missing the `ipairs` in `for _, v in ipairs(arr) do`?